# Store RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA keys and modulus in BigInteger

Tags: c#, rsa, biginteger

I am a student learning C# recently for a class and one assignment I have has us creating a blind signature protocol for a digital cash app. One of the requirements for this is to create a RSA public and private keys as well as modulus using the RSACryptoServiceProvider class and then store these values using BigInteger class. My question is then what is the method for storing these values in BigInteger as I understand they are not the same type.

(P.S. I am doing this in C# in Visual Studio 2015 if that helps)

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you ask your instructor?

Comment: My big question is that if i were to do something like BigInteger pubKey, would i then say something like rsa.exportparameters, or use a different method since export for rsa calls for a boolean? Like I said I'm fairly new to C# and data encryption.